# Extending MPEG4 Source Filter to other MediaTypes

Tags: video, ms-media-foundation

I'm creating an MFT video decoder to add support for codec that Media Foundation doesn't currently support to my application.  In this case it's the Hap codec.  This is working great for AVI files, but but MOV files it's not working.

I read in the MS documentation that the MPEG4 Source filter (which I believe is what handles MOV files) does support other unknown MediaTypes via the MFMPEG4Format_Base mechanism documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mpeg-4-file-source

So I added new SubTypes to my MFT factory via MFMPEG4Format_Base with the fourCC code, and registered it using MFTRegisterLocal() as usual.

The problem is Media Foundation still doesn't seem to consider using my MFT.  It doesn't even use the factory to create an instance of the MFT to see if it can connect it.

I'm not sure if this is related but I'm using IMFMediaEngine for playback, and register this MFT locally earlier.  It works fine for AVI files, but just not for MOV.

There is very little information online about MFMPEG4Format_Base, so I'm hoping someone here has experience with it and could offer a suggestion about what I'm doing wrong, or perhaps another approach to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Doe you have any sample Hap MOVs?

Comment: Yes here is one:
https://rh-testmedia.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HapCodec/Hap01-Jokyo-HAP-1000x400px-8Chunks.mov

Answer (score 1):

Stock Microsoft's [MPEG-4 Media Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mpeg-4-file-source#media-types) is capable to read [this sample MOV with HAP frame inside](https://rh-testmedia.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/HapCodec/Hap01-Jokyo-HAP-1000x400px-8Chunks.mov).

MSDN documentation is generally accurate but there is a nuance.

The track is indicated as FourCC 'Hap1' video and not `MFMPEG4Format_Base` as you suggested. You cannot extend the source because, generally speaking, it already does what it is expected to: it is capable to read from this file.

[image]

Further extensibility and support of playback of this type of content within Media Foundation pipeline assumes that there is a decoder MFT for this type of content. You need to install such MFT, if it is at all available, or develop your own.

Comment: I have created the custom MFT already for decoding these frames, and it works fine when using an AVI container, but not MOV container.  I've registered the MFT using MFTRegisterLocal() with a number of VIDEO major Types with Hap subtypes eg: 
  DEFINE_MEDIATYPE_GUID(MFVideoFormat_Hap, FCC('Hap1'));
I guess it could be the case that IMFMediaEngine's resolving of the MediaSession just isn't considering my MFT when using the MPEG4 Source Filter for some reason, but perhaps if I connect them manually it will work....hmmm

Comment: Solved it!  For some reason I have to define the FourCC backwards.  I will post my solution below.  Comments welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Roman is correct, the MPEG-4 Media Source can support other subtypes.  I managed to get it working for my use case, but I had to reverse the FOURCC ordering!

For AVI files I could just declare and use these GUIDS for the Hap subtype:

```
DEFINE_MEDIATYPE_GUID(MFVideoFormat_Hap, FCC('Hap1'));
```

And then register my MFT with MFTRegisterLocal(_instance, MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_DECODER...

However this didn't work with MOV containers.  I had to use the MFMPEG4Format_Base type and add the codec FOURCC but it only worked when I reversed the order:

```
//
// this macro creates a media type GUID from a FourCC, D3DFMT, or WAVE_FORMAT
// based on MFMPEG4Format_Base which defines GUIDS for unknown mediaTypes
// when using the MF MPEG-4 Source
//
#ifndef DEFINE_MPEG4_MEDIATYPE_GUID
#define DEFINE_MPEG4_MEDIATYPE_GUID(name, format) \
    DEFINE_GUID(name,                               \
    format, 0x767a, 0x494d, 0xb4, 0x78, 0xf2, 0x9d, 0x25, 0xdc, 0x90, 0x37);
#endif

DEFINE_MPEG4_MEDIATYPE_GUID(MFVideoFormat_MPEG4_Hap, FCC('1paH'));
```

I'm not sure why the ordering is reversed but it works for me.